# How to search for string between whitespace and marker? Python

Tags: python, datetime, substring, python-re

My problem is the following:
I have the string:

`datetime = "2021/04/07 08:30:00"`

I want to save in the variable hour, 08 and
I want to save in the variable minutes, 30

What I've done is the following:

```
import re
 
pat = re.compile(' (.*):')
hour = re.search(pat, datetime)
minutes = re.search(pat, datetime)
print(hour.group(1))
print(minutes.group(1))
```

What I obtain from the prints is
`08:30` and `30`, so the minutes are correct but for some reason that I'm not understanding, in the hours the first `:` is skipped and takes everything from the whitespace to the second `:`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use `minutes = datetime.split(':')[1]` and `hours = datetime.split(':')[0][-2:]`?

Comment: Please consider compiling the regex pattern instead of evaluating it multiple times, which can save considerable computational time in complex patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, no no, python has a much better approach with datetime.strptime

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

So for you:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_string = "2021/04/07 08:30:00"

# Considering date is in dd/mm/yyyy format
dt_object1 = datetime.strptime(dt_string, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

You want hours?

```
hours = dt_object1.hour
```

or minutes?

```
mins = dt_object1.minute
```

Now, if what you have presented is just an example of where you need to work around whitespace, then you could split the string up. Again with dt_string:

```
dt_string1 = dt_string.split(" ")
dateString = dt_string1.split("/")  # A list in [years, months, days]
timeString = dt_string2.split(":")  # A list in [hours, minutes, seconds]
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use `strptime` from datetime module which is recommended way to handle string dates in python.

`strptime` returns a datetime object from the string date, and this datetime object comes with all sorts of goodies like `date`, `time`, `hour`, `isoformat`, `timestamp` etc which makes working with datetimes breeze.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2021/04/07 08:30:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 7, 8, 30)
datetime.datetime.strptime("2021/04/07 08:30:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").hour
8
datetime.datetime.strptime("2021/04/07 08:30:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").second
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard `.` matches any single character, even the `:`. So `.*` matches the `08:30`.

Use:

```
hour = re.search('\ ([0-9]*):', datetime)
```

Output:

```
>>> hour.group(1)
'08'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below regex to make it non greedy and stop at first **:**

```
hour = re.search(' (.*?):', datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to what you are doing is to split the original datetime by the space into a variable such as dates, which will give you ['2021/04/07', '08:30:00']. You can then access the second value of the list variable dates and split it again by ':', to get the individual time, and access the parts of the list varaible time for hours, minutes, and seconds, from the variable time.

```
datetime = "2021/04/07 08:30:00"

dates = datetime.split(" ")
print(dates)

time = dates[1].split(":")
print(time)
```

Printing the code will give you

print(dates) --> ['2021/04/07', '08:30:00']

print(time) --> ['08', '30', '00']

You can access individual parts of time with time[0] for '08', time[1] for '30' etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re.compile` with named capture groups and iterate:

```py
inp = "Hello World 2021/04/07 08:30:00 Goodbye"
r = re.compile(r'\b\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} (?P<hour>\d{2}):(?P<minute>\d{2}):\d{2}\b')
output = [m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(inp)]
print(output[0]['hour'])    # 08
print(output[0]['minute'])  # 30
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple datetime question.  Python already has the ability to do exactly what you need.  3 steps:

- use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to generate your date time from your string.
- you can get the formatting options [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime)
- return just the hour or minute from the datetime object
- 

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_string = "2021/04/07 08:30:00"
dt_object = datetime.strptime(dt_string, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

print(dt_object)
print(dt_object.hour, dt_object.minute)

# 2021-04-07 08:30:00
# 8 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that thing using Striptime in some cases if you need to do with string you can search those thing using +[what are the things inside here you can make it here example 0-7 or a-z or A-Z or symbols]+

```
import re
datetime = "2021/04/07 08:30:00"
#here you need to make a change
hour = re.search(' (.*):+[0-7]+:', datetime)
minutes = re.search(':(.*):', datetime)
print(hour.group(1))
print(minutes.group(1))
```